# Simple HTML/PHP Refuses to work

Tags: php, html

Here is poster dot php

```
<?php
$FILENAME = "poster.php";
$txt = "data.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both 
fields are set
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
$txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2']; 
fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
fclose($fh); // Close the file
}
?>
```

Here is my HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Field 1 & 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="poster.php" method="post">
        What is your name?<br>
        <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="field2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried everything to make this work when i put it in a debugger it says the file should end on the first line. When I run the file all i get is a white screen. I'm in desperate need of help.

Comment: If your code displays exactly like what you posted above you need to comment out the "fields are set" like so `//fields are set`.  Then I would look into a good code editor to help you find your errors easier.  Atom is a good choice and it also has a PHP linter that works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing anything after appending your form data in your poster.php file. You can get the file contents in the following way...

Html form:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Field 1 & 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="poster.php" method="post">
        What is your name?<br>
        <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="field2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in `poster.php`

```
 <?php
   $FILENAME = "poster.php";
   $txt = "data.txt"; 
   if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both 
   //fields are set
      $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
      $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'].PHP_EOL; 
      fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
      fclose($fh); // Close the file
      echo file_get_contents("data.txt");
   }
?>
```

As per requirement, write PHP code and HTML code inside a single file and remove the action attribute of the form  in the following code ...

```
    <?php
     //$FILENAME = "poster.php";
      $txt = "data.txt"; 
      if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) { // check if both 
      //fields are set
      $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
      $txt=$_POST['field1'].' - '.$_POST['field2'].PHP_EOL ; 
      fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
      fclose($fh); // Close the file
      //echo file_get_contents("data.txt");
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Field 1 & 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
        What is your name?<br>
        <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="field2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this worked. Thank You So Much. When I hit submit it shows whatever I inputted. Is it possible to stay on the same page after submission?

Comment: Also, after submission, this shows the whole list which is bad for privacy reasons. any way around that?

Comment: @JohnJansen updated the answer! Do accept and upvote if it worked for you!!

Answer (score 0):

action attribute of form should be file name where you submit your form.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
```

Here it is 'action.php' but you have to submit it on poster dot php.

Answer (score 0):

please check it:

```
<form action="poster.php" method="post">
```

Form action will be your main file name(poster.php) and after form post, you can easily get all the form fields data on poster.php file.

> you wotre this file name -> poster dot php means poster.php ?

Comment: still doesn't work. also I can't really understand your words

Comment: just add poster.php in you file action then submit the form simple

Comment: I already did that. the php file doesn't run or do anything. i click submit and the screen turns white